# generate form fields from vocabulary (RDFS)

Tags: django, django-forms, rdf, semantic-web

I have a vocabulary described with RDFS, consider for example the ["Friend of a Friend" (FOAF)](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/).

Now I want to populate my database, so I want to insert the classes (the Person classes) and their relations (the friendship). I want to do that with a web page with the appropriate form field connected to a back-end server.

My ontology is more complicated than the FOAF (but it is based on it), so I am searching for a tool that automatically creates the web forms.

Presently I am not linked to a particular technology, but I would like to stay with RDF since I am also using rdflib, in particular for querying. Django seems to be a solution, but I am not sure how it interacts with RDF.

Comment: Good question, although probably not quite for StackOverflow. Anyway, I'd also be interested to know about open source tools with such capability. I'm currently using TopBraid composer for that, but I'd like to learn if there are free alternatives. In fact, I have used one free alternative: Web Protégé.